# How can I pin an element in the top row(right side) of a flexbox flow and still allow items to flow immediately below it when it exists?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

## The Background

I have been tasked with changing our absolute-positioned CSS to use flex-box so that when a certain div(currently positioned upper right of the block it resides in) is not displayed the block next to it(currently positioned top of the block it resides in right the width of the other block) will flow to the edge.

[image: full]

[image: no blue]

That's the easy part.

## The Problem

The problem is that the block that is currently upper-right needs to stay there and the other block needs to flow below it.

The two blocks are likely to not change size, but the third element(red) is an image that changes during different circumstances and cannot be guaranteed to be a specific size.

### Pinned block present:

[image: full]

[image: short]

[image: shorter]

### Pinned block not present:

[image: full no blue]

[image: short no blue]

[image: shorter no blue]

## The Stripped Down Code

### Non-Flex Equivalent

I was able to replicate this functionality [without flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/0znmpwoa/1/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="lefty">

    </div>
    <div class="flexy">
        <div class="righty">

        </div>
        <div class="droppy">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.parent{
}

.lefty{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    float:left;
}

.droppy{
    float:right;
    width:175px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00ff00;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-right:25px;
}

.righty{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#0000ff;
    float:right;
    display
}
```

### Flexbox Woes

I have not been able to make heads or tails of what a [flexbox solution](https://jsfiddle.net/j1ud8whc/5/) looks like, as if I use flex the far-right item flows down and if I have a separate flex div parent then it will either not flow directly under the far-right item, will move the whole flex parent to the next line, or will jam the flex area to it's minimum size.

#### HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="lefty">

    </div>
    <div class="spacer">

    </div>
    <div class="droppy">

    </div>
    <div class="righty">

    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
}

.lefty{
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}

.spacer{
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:1;
}

.droppy{
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    width:175px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00ff00;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:25px;
}

.righty{
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#0000ff;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using order property for flex items:
resize screen to  smaller width to see change!

```css
*{
margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
}

.lefty{
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}

.spacer{
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:1;
}

.droppy{
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    width:175px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00ff00;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:25px;
}

.righty{
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#0000ff;
    margin-left: auto;
}
@media(max-width:600px){
  .droppy{
order:4;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-right:0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="lefty">

    </div>
    <div class="spacer">

    </div>
    <div class="droppy">

    </div>
    <div class="righty">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works well [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), although it would have to be very precisely calibrated so that it doesn't flip the two  before the size is too small and if the size of either changes it would flop them too early or too late

Comment: this will work on `600px` which is the total `width` of all divs with `margin` : 200px(lefty)+200px(righty)+(175px+25px(margin))=600px

Comment: You're right it does work for the problem as originally provided. I have updated the question to include a note about how one of the elements changes size during different circumstances.